# how to set relative path in nuget.config?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I currently have the following `nuget.config` file. With automatic package restore it will create a package folder that is one level up from my solution folder. For example if my solution folder is on my desktop, the package folder will be generated within a `/lib` folder on my desktop. I would like for it to generate the `/lib` folder within my solution folder. How do I change the relative path to accomplish this?

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration"
      value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath"
      value="../lib" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

For example,

Bad: \desktop\lib\

Good: \desktop\mysolution\lib\

I tried this:

```
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath"
      value="/lib" />
  </config>
```

..and the package restore directory becomes `c:\lib` which is unexpected behavior.

Comment: So what happens if you make it just "`lib`"?

Comment: Just use `lib` as Jeroen has already commented.

Comment: Agree with Jeroen Mostert's suggestion. Please quote his/her comment as answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Comment: What @JeroenMostert said - and maybe even `"./lib"` would work, too. In most environments, `"/"` denotes the root of something.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, please make sure your NuGet.Config file is added under your solution directory after you use "lib" path in that path.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I remove

```
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath"
      value="../lib" />
  </config>
```

...from `nuget.config`

Or

if I complete delete `nuget.config` (and use all defaults)

That the default behavior will be to create and add packages to this folder:

\desktop\mysolution\packages\

and while that is not named '`lib`' it hardly matters - my key issue was to get the packages in to the solution folder.